# In shell script, how did 'if-else' in a for loop executed? Why did it only print once for a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I wrote a shell snippet shown as below:

```
is_first=t
for f in "$path"/"m*"
do
    printf "%s\n" $f
    printf "%s\n" $is_first

    if [[ "$is_first" = "t" ]]; then
        is_first=f
        printf "%s\n" $is_first
    else
        printf "%s\n" $is_first
    fi

    printf "%s\n" $is_first
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
./merge_non-null
./merge_non-null_bak.sh
./merge_non-null.sh
t
f
f
```

I'm wondering, **how did `if-else` execute in a for loop?** It seems it runs only for the first loop, and all skipped afterwards.

Also, **why does `printf "%s\n" $is_first` only executed for for the first loop?**
The output I expected is (note the sequence). I believe I've missed something. Sorry if it's too stupid.

```
./merge_non-null
t
f
f
./merge_non-null_bak.sh
f
f
f
./merge_non-null.sh
f
f
f
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quoting is incorrect.  The `"m*"` does not get expanded, because it's in double quotes, so you loop over the literal string; and so the loop only executes once.  Then you incorrectly *omit* quotes inside the loop, and so the shell expands the wildcard in the argument to the first `printf`.  Without quotes, `printf` with this format string prints one line per token in the expanded string; so you get multiple output lines from a single iteration of the loop, from that first `printf`.

With correct quoting, your script would become

```
is_first=t
for f in "$path/m"*
do
    printf "%s\n" "$f"
    printf "%s\n" "$is_first"

    if [[ "$is_first" = "t" ]]; then
        is_first=f
        printf "%s\n" "$is_first"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$is_first"
    fi

    printf "%s\n" "$is_first"
done
```

See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable)

Comment: or `for f in "$path/m"*`